# How to find harddisk access usage as a percentage like in Windows Task Manager

Tags: hard-drive, system-monitor

I need to find the `hard disk` access as a percentage like in `Windows Task manager`. My hard disk light keep on light up for several minutes when I am working on `Android studio`, and I need to find what app causes it to blink that much. I tries using `System Monitor` but it only shows the `disk usage`. How can I view my `disk access` as a percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iotop tool to help you find what you are looking for.

Type the following command in your terminal:

```
sudo iotop -o
```

and look in to **IO>** and **COMMAND** sections.

If you don't have the iotop tool, type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install iotop
```

to install it.

Comment: it is not what I need, I need a graphical interface like `System Monitor` with current disk usage as a percentage like in `windows task manager`

Comment: I am sure that iotop will help you to resolve your issue and if you are searching for GUI program that you could double click like System Monitor(the Disk part of it), there isn't one.